# Undefined reference to sequence when trying to input a vector

Tags: c++11, vector, undefined-reference

This seems a simple but somehow the compile sends this error message which I'm not able understand thus correct my code.

This is a simplified version of what I did, just so it can appear the error for you:

**Main.cpp**

```
include "myfunction.h"
int main(){
    std::vector<int> myVet = {1,4,3};
    sequence(1,2,1,myVet);
}
```

---

**myfunction.h**

```
#include <vector>
/*funtion creates a sequence*/
void sequence(int start, int end, 
              int step, std::vector<int> skip);
```

---

**myfunction.cpp**

```
#include "myfunction.h"

void sequence(int start, int end, 
              int step, std::vector<int> skip){
     auto x = 0;
};
```

This gives me an error message which says

```
In function 'main':
/home/machina/Documents/Grafos&Redes/Implementação/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to 'sequence(int, int, int, std::vector <int, std::allocator<int> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you please explain me why it appears?

This is the following command which I've been using for compiling

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g  -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp -o main.out
```

Comment: You need to build all source files `myfunction.cpp` is missing while building. Change your command line to `... -Werror main.cpp myfunction.cpp -o main.out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing `main.cpp` to g++.

g++ needs to know about myfunction.cpp where your function is defined so as to compile and link it to your program.

The command to use should be:

`g++ -std=c++11 -g  -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp myfunction.cpp -o main.out`